# How to Text floating in block next to image?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying with different display settings (block + inline for text etc.) 
    but it is still not working. 
looking my site: http://maroccouture.com/produit/foie-gras/

Comment: show your code - it will help to understand you problem

Comment: @lexxl https://jsfiddle.net/x6jkb9yw/ look my jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap heading and paragraph around image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971958/wrap-heading-and-paragraph-around-image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to my text to be next image look my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/x6jkb9yw/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your're asking

```
.summary entry-summary {
  float: right;
}
.images {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes Exactly but ,I Already try this but not working https://jsfiddle.net/x6jkb9yw/

Comment: you are putting css code in javascript field ) it should be on top-right but not on bottom left

Comment: Yeah but still not working can u edite please my jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x6jkb9yw/2/ here you go - stretch the bottom-right column with content to see the result (i removed your `width` parameters because there were wrong)

Comment: I dont understand why not working in my site ? http://maroccouture.com/produit/foie-gras/

Comment: all I see that on your website there are still no `float` for both blocks. comment all your styles for those blocks, then apply float for them to allign correctly. and after that add all your current styles step-by-step. and you will see at what step your code crushes

Answer (score 0):

I can not edit the js fiddle file as am new to all this, so not sure how yet.

1. Put a div id="container"  around your div class="images" and div class="summary"

So it is just .summary and .images div inside #container

2. In the css, add and change so:

.container {width: 950px !important; display:inline-block;}

.images {float:left !important; width:400px !important; display:inline-block; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important;}

.summary {float:right !important; width:500px !important; display:inline-block; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important;}

This will put the text next to the image. You can then play around with the css to style it how you like, and eliminate the !important 's from the css one by one, checking to make sure it has changed anything.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i try but not working in my site link :http://maroccouture.com/produit/foie-gras/ any idea ?